# Use PostGIS table in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I have created a model in QGIS that uses data to create a set of tables in PostgreSQL via the "**Export to PostgreSQL**" process

Is there a processing command that will allow me to access these tables as part of my model?

At the moment I have to stop and add them manually from the browser

This is latest version of QGIS 3.8. The tables do not have a geometry column

Comment: If the tables don't have a geometry column, they're not PostGIS tables, just tables.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out to be quite simple. You use the "**PostgreSQL execute and Load**" process step. And the output from this SQL will be available as inputs to other steps.

Also worth knowing that this does not work unless your query outputs a geometry (despite it being marked optional). I faked it with:-

```
SELECT distinct code,
       ST_GEOMFROMEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(0 0)') as geom,
etc...
```

And then set Unique ID field to "code" and Geometry Field to "geom"